# Poisson Distribution from Samples of Varying Sizes

Tags: poisson-distribution, cluster-sample

Can I apply a Poisson distribution if I have different sample sizes for each cluster? My experiment is about diversity in International Baccalaureate vs non-IB classes, and I used single-stage cluster sampling where subgroups of the population were selected, and all individuals within each selected subgroup were included in the sample. I then recorded the amount of white and non-white students per class. However, each class size is different, so would I be able to approximate a Poisson mean of non-white students for each class by finding the ratio of the mean where I set all class sizes to the same amount? Or would a Poisson distribution not work in this scenario?

Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: I don't think I have fully comprehended the domain knowledge, but at a glance I would suggest that you consider a multi-level modelling approach to handle the cluster sampling. Since it sounds like you are considering count data, Poisson would at least tick that box. As long as you follow [a good workflow](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01808), I think you should go [NUTS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4246) and eventually try out a multilevel model with Poisson-distributed outcomes.

Comment: You can use class size as an offset, peruse the tag [tag:offset]

Comment: Thanks Galen, I think a multi-level modelling approach would work, where the higher hierarchy would be the school population and the lower hierarchy would be the individual classes. However, I don't know how to implement that in a Poisson distribution.